# Oracle SQL- Flag records based on record's date vs history

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my 1st post on the forum. Usually I was able to find what I needed - but to tell the truth - I am not really sure how to ask a correct question to the issue. Therefore, please accept my apologies if there already is an answer on the forum and I missed it.

I am running the following code in an Oracle database via Benthic Software:

```
SELECT
T1."REGION"
, T1."COUNTRY"
, T1."IDNum"
, T1."CUSTOMER"
, T1."BUSSINESS"
, T3."FISCALYEARMONTH"
, T3."FISCALYEAR"
, SUM(T4."VALUE") 
,"HISTORICAL_PURCHASE_FLAG"

FROM
"DATABASE"."SALES" T4
, "DATABASE"."CUSTOMER" T1
, "DATABASE"."PRODUCT" T2
, "DATABASE"."TIME" T3

WHERE
T4."CUSTOMERID" = T1."CUSTOMERID"
AND T4."PRODUCTID" = T2."PRODUCTID"
AND T4."DATEID" = T3."DATEID"
AND T3."FISCALYEAR" IN ('2016')
AND T1."COUNTRY" IN ('ENGLAND', 'France')


GROUP BY
T1."REGION"
, T1."COUNTRY"
, T1."IDNum"
, T1."CUSTOMER"
, T1."BUSSINESS"
, T3."FISCALYEARMONTH"
, T3."FISCALYEAR"
;
```

This query provides me with information on transactions. As you can see above, I would like to add a column named "HISTORICAL_PURCHASE_FLAG".

I would like the query to take CUSTOMER and FISCALYEARMONTH. Then, I would like to check if there are any transactions registered for the CUSTOMER, up to 2 years in the past.

So lets say I get the following result:

```
LineNum REGION  COUNTRY IDNum   CUSTOMER            BUSSINESS       FISCALYEARMONTH FISCALYEAR  VALUE      HISTORICAL_PURCHASE_FLAG
1       Europe  ENGLAND 255     Abraxo Cleaner Co.  Chemicals       201605           2016       34,567.00   
2       Europe  FRANCE  123     Metal Trade          Heavy          201602           2016       12,500.00   
3       Europe  ENGLAND 255     Abraxo Cleaner Co.  Chemicals       201601           2016       8,400.00
```

LineNum 1 shows transaction for Abraxo Cleaner Co. registered on 201605. And LineNum 3 is also for Abraxo Cleaner Co. but registered on 201601. What I would need the query to do, is to flag LineNum 1 as 'Existing'. Because there was a previous transaction registered.

On the other hand, LineNum 3 was the first time transactions was registered for Abraxo Cleaner Co. so the line would be flagged as 'New'.

To sum up, I would like for each row of data to be treated individually. And to check if there are any previous records of data for CUSTOMER & FISCALYEARMONTH - 24 months.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: there are a couple of ways to do this. You could have a subquery to exract the data for the new column, or my prefered method would be to create a function which does the heavy lifting and call this as part of the SELECT. You could also do something with CASE statements but that would get complicate. Also, is your fiscal_year column really a string? numeric would be a better design.

Comment: " 2 years in the past" from now or from FISCALYEARMONTH ?

Comment: The query narrows down transactions from 2016 year only for these countries: `AND T1."COUNTRY" IN ('ENGLAND', 'France')`. Do you want to check if there are any previous records also **only for these two contries**, or for any country <> ENGLAND & FRANCE ?

Comment: @David, if your question is regarding PL/SQL (Oracle), remove the `mysql` and `sql-server` tags since those are different database products.

Comment: @Dan Guzman, I have removed mysql and sql-server tags. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Mottor, It's 2 years in the past from FISCALYEARMONTH in the record. So in terms of LineNum 1 it would be checking back up to 201405; For LineNum 3 it would be checking back to 201401. 
Also, to specify, I do not need to find all previous transactions. LineNum 1, which was registered in 201605, would find that LineNum 3 was registered in 201601 and that would be enough to mark it as 'Existing'.

Comment: @kordirko, The full query should take data from 20 countries actually. I have limited the number of countries to 2, in order to make the query easier to read and to show that the query pulls data for more than 1 country.

Comment: @davegreen100, Columns FISCALYEARMONTH and FISCALYEARMONTH are both set to NUMBER(10). 

I was trying something with CASE but with no success. And unfortunately creating functions is beyond my current skill level.

I am currently trying to use WITH clause with the main query. Something along these lines:

`WITH LastDate ("IDNum", "FISCALYEARMONTH")
AS (SELECT T1."IDNum", MAX (T3."FISCALYEARMONTH")
FROM
"DATABASE"."CUSTOMER" T1
, "DATABASE"."TIME" T3
WHERE
T3."FISCALYEARMONTH" BETWEEN '201406' AND '201606'
GROUP BY
T1."MM_ID")`

Comment: FYI: I removed the PL/SQL tag, as the question only deals with SQL. Unless, of course, you really don't mind a PL/SQL function/procedure solution to your problem. But I doubt it.

Comment: Tell us the structure of the "TIME" table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [LAG](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm) function:

```
SELECT
"REGION"
, "COUNTRY"
, "IDNum"
, "CUSTOMER"
, "BUSSINESS"
, "FISCALYEARMONTH"
, "FISCALYEAR"
, SUM("VALUE") 
, MAX(CASE WHEN to_date(prev_fym,'YYYYMM')  >= ADD_MONTHS (to_date("FISCALYEARMONTH",'YYYYMM'), -24) THEN 'Existing' 
           ELSE NULL END) "HISTORICAL_PURCHASE_FLAG"
FROM
(
    SELECT
    T1."REGION"
    , T1."COUNTRY"
    , T1."IDNum"
    , T1."CUSTOMER"
    , T1."BUSSINESS"
    , T3."FISCALYEARMONTH"
    , T3."FISCALYEAR"
    , T4."VALUE"
    , LAG ("FISCALYEARMONTH", 1) OVER (PARTITION BY T1."IDNum" ORDER BY T3."FISCALYEARMONTH" DESC) prev_fym 
    FROM
    "DATABASE"."SALES" T4
    , "DATABASE"."CUSTOMER" T1
    , "DATABASE"."PRODUCT" T2
    , "DATABASE"."TIME" T3
    WHERE
    T4."CUSTOMERID" = T1."CUSTOMERID"
    AND T4."PRODUCTID" = T2."PRODUCTID"
    AND T4."DATEID" = T3."DATEID"
    AND T1."COUNTRY" IN ('ENGLAND', 'France')
    AND T3."FISCALYEAR" IN ('2014','2015','2016')
)
WHERE "FISCALYEAR" IN ('2016')
GROUP BY
"REGION"
, "COUNTRY"
, "IDNum"
, "CUSTOMER"
, "BUSSINESS"
, "FISCALYEARMONTH"
, "FISCALYEAR"
;
```

Comment: This query can't work, since the original query filter out all years except `AND T3."FISCALYEAR" IN ('2016')`, so a result of the subquery contains no data for previous years.

Comment: @kordiko Repaired. Cannot test it.

Comment: @kordiko Unfortunately I get an error: "ORA-00904: T1."REGION": invalid identifier". Looks as if query cannot refer to nested query's aliases?

Comment: @David it's not my answer, please rather send this comment do  Mottor

Comment: @Mottor Unfortunately I get an error: "ORA-00904: T1."REGION": invalid identifier". Looks as if query cannot refer to nested query's aliases?

Comment: @Mottor Thank you Mottor! It looks like LAG Function worked perfectly. Please give me some time to go through the results to be 100% certain but I have high hopes.

Comment: @David Sorry, I have forgotten to delete the table name from group by

Answer (score 0):

Using a simplified "input" table... You can use the `LAG()` analytic function and a comparison condition to populate your last column. I assume your `fiscalyearmonth` is a number - if it is a character field, wrap `fiscalyearmonth` within `TO_NUMBER()`. (It would be much better if in fact you stored these as true Oracle dates, perhaps `date 2016-06-01` instead of `201606`, but I worked with what you have currently... and took advantage that in numeric format, "24 months ago" simply means "subtract 200").

```
with inputs (linenum, idnum, fiscalyearmonth) as (
       select 1, 255, 201605 from dual union all
       select 2, 123, 201602 from dual union all
       select 3, 255, 201601 from dual union all
       select 4, 255, 201210 from dual
     )
select linenum, idnum, fiscalyearmonth, 
       case when fiscalyearmonth 
                 - lag(fiscalyearmonth) 
                           over (partition by idnum order by fiscalyearmonth) < 200
            then 'Existing' else 'New' end         as flag
from   inputs
order by linenum;


   LINENUM      IDNUM FISCALYEARMONTH FLAG
---------- ---------- --------------- --------
         1        255          201605 Existing
         2        123          201602 New
         3        255          201601 New
         4        255          201210 New
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution might be to outer Join "DATABASE"."SALES" T4 a second time as T5, wilter the fiscal year via WHERE to < t4.FiscalYear-2. If the Column is NULL, the record is new, if the outer join results in a value, the record is historic.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve using row_number() function as below... modify as per  your need...I assumed 2 years (means previous 24 months from sysdate ).
You can run the sub-queries separately to check how its working.

```
Select 
"REGION"
,"COUNTRY"
,"IDNum"
,"CUSTOMER"
,"BUSSINESS"
,"FISCALYEARMONTH"
,"FISCALYEAR"
,"VALUE"
, ( case when ( TXNNO = 1 or TOTAL_TXN_LAST24MTH = 0 ) then 'New' else 'Existing' end ) as "HISTORICAL_PURCHASE_FLAG"  -- if no txn in last 24 month or its first txn then 'new' else 'existing'
from
(
  select 
  SubQry."REGION"
  , SubQry."COUNTRY"
  , SubQry."IDNum"
  , SubQry."CUSTOMER"
  , SubQry."BUSSINESS"
  , SubQry."FISCALYEARMONTH"
  , SUBQRY."FISCALYEAR"
  , SUBQRY."VALUE"
  , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by SUBQRY."REGION",SUBQRY."COUNTRY",SUBQRY."IDNum",SUBQRY."CUSTOMER",SUBQRY."BUSSINESS" order by SUBQRY."FISCALYEARMONTH") as TXNNO,
  , SUM(case when (TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'YYYYMM')) - SUBQRY."FISCALYEARMONTH") < 24 then 1 else 0 end) as TOTAL_TXN_LAST24MTH
  From
  (
    SELECT
    T1."REGION"
    , T1."COUNTRY"
    , T1."IDNum"
    , T1."CUSTOMER"
    , T1."BUSSINESS"
    , T3."FISCALYEARMONTH"
    , T3."FISCALYEAR"
    , SUM(T4."VALUE") as VALUE
    FROM
    "DATABASE"."SALES" T4
    , "DATABASE"."CUSTOMER" T1
    , "DATABASE"."PRODUCT" T2
    , "DATABASE"."TIME" T3
    WHERE
    T4."CUSTOMERID" = T1."CUSTOMERID"
    AND T4."PRODUCTID" = T2."PRODUCTID"
    AND T4."DATEID" = T3."DATEID"
    AND T3."FISCALYEAR" IN ('2016')
    AND T1."COUNTRY" IN ('ENGLAND', 'France')
    GROUP BY
    T1."REGION"
    , T1."COUNTRY"
    , T1."IDNum"
    , T1."CUSTOMER"
    , T1."BUSSINESS"
    , T3."FISCALYEARMONTH"
    , T3."FISCALYEAR"
  ) SUBQRY
);
```