# Combine CONCAT and LAG functions

Tags: sql, oracle

To start, this relates to a post on how to [Oracle SQL- Flag records based on record's date vs history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38183328/flag-records-based-on-records-date-vs-history), which was successfully resolved. I have decided to open a new topic for two reasons:

1. This is a new issue (although it relates to the previous one).
2. Someone may find the solution from the original post useful, so I did not want it changed.

I am currently running the following query (provided by @Mottor):

```
SELECT
"REGION"
, "COUNTRY"
, "IDNum"
, "CUSTOMER"
, "BUSSINESS"
, "FISCALYEARMONTH"
, "FISCALYEAR"
, SUM("VALUE") 
, MAX(CASE WHEN to_date(prev_fym,'YYYYMM')  >= ADD_MONTHS (to_date("FISCALYEARMONTH",'YYYYMM'), -24) THEN 'Existing' 
           ELSE 'New ' END) "HISTORICAL_PURCHASE_FLAG"
FROM
(
    SELECT
    T1."REGION"
    , T1."COUNTRY"
    , T1."IDNum"
    , T1."CUSTOMER"
    , T2."BUSSINESS"
    , T3."FISCALYEARMONTH"
    , T3."FISCALYEAR"
    , T4."VALUE"
    , LAG ("FISCALYEARMONTH", 1) OVER (PARTITION BY T1."IDNum" ORDER BY T3."FISCALYEARMONTH" DESC) prev_fym 
    FROM
    "DATABASE"."SALES" T4
    , "DATABASE"."CUSTOMER" T1
    , "DATABASE"."PRODUCT" T2
    , "DATABASE"."TIME" T3
    WHERE
    T4."CUSTOMERID" = T1."CUSTOMERID"
    AND T4."PRODUCTID" = T2."PRODUCTID"
    AND T4."DATEID" = T3."DATEID"
    AND T1."COUNTRY" IN ('ENGLAND', 'France')
    AND T3."FISCALYEAR" IN ('2014','2015','2016')
)
WHERE "FISCALYEAR" IN ('2016')
GROUP BY
"REGION"
, "COUNTRY"
, "IDNum"
, "CUSTOMER"
, "BUSSINESS"
, "FISCALYEARMONTH"
, "FISCALYEAR"
;
```

As a result I get a list of all transactions from fiscal year 2016. In addition, LAG function allows me to flag records as 'New' or 'Existing', based on "IDNum" and "FISCALYEARMONTH". I get the following result:

```
LineNum REGION  COUNTRY IDNum   CUSTOMER            BUSSINESS       FISCALYEARMONTH FISCALYEAR  VALUE        HISTORICAL_PURCHASE_FLAG
1       Europe  ENGLAND 255     Abraxo Cleaner Co.  Chemicals       201605           2016       34,567.00    Existing   
2       Europe  FRANCE  123     Metal Trade         Heavy           201602           2016       12,500.00    Existing
3       Europe  ENGLAND 255     Abraxo Cleaner Co.  Mining          201601           2016       8,400.00     New
```

The issue I am facing at the moment is that a single customer can actually belong to multiple businesses. If you look at the above example, you will notice that Abraxo Cleaner Co. belongs to Chemicals and Mining.

I was trying to create a new column called "CUSTOMER_BUSSINESS_KEY" which would be a concatenation: `CONCAT(T1."IDNum",T2."BUSSINESS")`.

Next, I wanted to modify the LAG function as follows: `LAG ("FISCALYEARMONTH", 1) OVER (PARTITION BY "CUSTOMER_BUSSINESS_KEY" ORDER BY T3."FISCALYEARMONTH" DESC) prev_fym`. This should allow me to get records flagged as 'New' and 'Existing'based on the newly created column, instead of "IDNum".

Problem is, when I run the query I get an error message saying:

> ORA-00904: "CUSTOMER_BUSSINESS_KEY": invalid identifier

My understanding is that SQL cannot find table name for "CUSTOMER_BUSSINESS_KEY". Unfortunately I cannot figure out a way around it.

Comment: You  can't use an alias within the same Select. But why don't you simply use two columns: `PARTITION BY T1."IDNum",T2."BUSSINESS"`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Because I am using Oracle SQL Database.

Comment: @dnoeth It did not occur to me to refer to 2 tables. I have used `LAG ("FISCALYEARMONTH", 1) OVER (PARTITION BY T1."IDNum",T2."BUSSINESS" ORDER BY T3."FISCALYEARMONTH" DESC) prev_fym` and the query is running. I will check the results and let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use an alias within the same Select, either add another Derived Table or use the calculation instead:

```
SELECT
"REGION"
, "COUNTRY"
, "IDNum"
, "CUSTOMER"
, "BUSSINESS"
, "CUSTOMER_BUSSINESS_KEY"
, "FISCALYEARMONTH"
, "FISCALYEAR"
, SUM("VALUE") 
, MAX(CASE WHEN to_date(prev_fym,'YYYYMM')  >= ADD_MONTHS (to_date("FISCALYEARMONTH",'YYYYMM'), -24) THEN 'Existing' 
           ELSE 'New ' END) "HISTORICAL_PURCHASE_FLAG"
FROM
(
    SELECT
    T1."REGION"
    , T1."COUNTRY"
    , T1."IDNum"
    , T1."CUSTOMER"
    , T2."BUSSINESS"
    , CONCAT(T1."IDNum",T2."BUSSINESS") AS "CUSTOMER_BUSSINESS_KEY"
    , T3."FISCALYEARMONTH"
    , T3."FISCALYEAR"
    , T4."VALUE"
    , LAG ("FISCALYEARMONTH", 1)
      OVER (PARTITION BY CONCAT(T1."IDNum",T2."BUSSINESS")
            ORDER BY T3."FISCALYEARMONTH" DESC) prev_fym 
    FROM
    "DATABASE"."SALES" T4
    , "DATABASE"."CUSTOMER" T1
    , "DATABASE"."PRODUCT" T2
    , "DATABASE"."TIME" T3
    WHERE
    T4."CUSTOMERID" = T1."CUSTOMERID"
    AND T4."PRODUCTID" = T2."PRODUCTID"
    AND T4."DATEID" = T3."DATEID"
    AND T1."COUNTRY" IN ('ENGLAND', 'France')
    AND T3."FISCALYEAR" IN ('2014','2015','2016')
)
WHERE "FISCALYEAR" IN ('2016')
GROUP BY
"REGION"
, "COUNTRY"
, "IDNum"
, "CUSTOMER"
, "BUSSINESS"
, "FISCALYEARMONTH"
, "FISCALYEAR"
;
```

But you can also simply use multiple columns in PARTITION:

```
SELECT
"REGION"
, "COUNTRY"
, "IDNum"
, "CUSTOMER"
, "BUSSINESS"
, "FISCALYEARMONTH"
, "FISCALYEAR"
, SUM("VALUE") 
, MAX(CASE WHEN to_date(prev_fym,'YYYYMM')  >= ADD_MONTHS (to_date("FISCALYEARMONTH",'YYYYMM'), -24) THEN 'Existing' 
           ELSE 'New ' END) "HISTORICAL_PURCHASE_FLAG"
FROM
(
    SELECT
    T1."REGION"
    , T1."COUNTRY"
    , T1."IDNum"
    , T1."CUSTOMER"
    , T2."BUSSINESS"
    , T3."FISCALYEARMONTH"
    , T3."FISCALYEAR"
    , T4."VALUE"
    , LAG ("FISCALYEARMONTH", 1)
      OVER (PARTITION BY T1."IDNum",T2."BUSSINESS"
            ORDER BY T3."FISCALYEARMONTH" DESC) prev_fym 
    FROM
    "DATABASE"."SALES" T4
    , "DATABASE"."CUSTOMER" T1
    , "DATABASE"."PRODUCT" T2
    , "DATABASE"."TIME" T3
    WHERE
    T4."CUSTOMERID" = T1."CUSTOMERID"
    AND T4."PRODUCTID" = T2."PRODUCTID"
    AND T4."DATEID" = T3."DATEID"
    AND T1."COUNTRY" IN ('ENGLAND', 'France')
    AND T3."FISCALYEAR" IN ('2014','2015','2016')
)
WHERE "FISCALYEAR" IN ('2016')
GROUP BY
"REGION"
, "COUNTRY"
, "IDNum"
, "CUSTOMER"
, "BUSSINESS"
, "FISCALYEARMONTH"
, "FISCALYEAR"
;
```

Comment: I have used multiple columns in partition. Thank you kindly, it worked perfectly!