# Oracle SQL - SUM data based on a result from a nested query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a nested query which is supposed to do the following:

1. Bottom query creates column named "INITIATIVE" and flags records in that column based on "BU_ID".
2. Then SUBQRY, uses LAG function to check if any records came 5 years back. This is based on "CUSTID" and "INITIATIVE" (which was defined in step 1).
3. Finally, top query created column named "TRANSACTION_FLAG" which will flag records 'New' or 'Existing'. Query checks if there were any transactions 60 months back.

Please see query below:

```
SELECT
"REGION"
, "COUNTRY"
, "CUSTID"
, "CUSTOMER"
, "VERTICAL"
, "DATE_YEARMONTH"
, "DATE_YEAR"
, "ORDER_VALUE"
, "INITIATIVE"
, MAX(CASE WHEN TO_DATE("PREV_FYM_INITIATIVE",'YYYYMM')  >= ADD_MONTHS (TO_DATE("DATE_YEARMONTH",'YYYYMM'), -60) THEN 'Existing' ELSE 'New' END) "TRANSACTION_FLAG"
FROM
(
SELECT
 SUBQRY."REGION"
, SUBQRY."COUNTRY"
, SUBQRY."CUSTID"
, SUBQRY."CUSTOMER"
, SUBQRY."VERTICAL"
, SUBQRY."DATE_YEARMONTH"
, SUBQRY."DATE_YEAR"
, SUBQRY."ORDER_VALUE"
, SUBQRY."INITIATIVE"
, LAG (SUBQRY."DATE_YEARMONTH", 1) OVER (PARTITION BY SUBQRY."CUSTID", SUBQRY."INITIATIVE" ORDER BY "DATE_YEARMONTH" ASC) "PREV_FYM_INITIATIVE"
FROM
(
SELECT
        T1."REGION"
        , T1."COUNTRY"
        , T1."CUSTID"
        , T1."CUSTOMER"
        , T1."VERTICAL"
        , T3."DATE_YEARMONTH"
        , T3."DATE_YEAR"
        , T4."ORDER_VALUE"
        , T3."DATE_DESC"
        , (CASE
                    WHEN T2."BU_ID" IN ('ACC', 'LXC', 'OTP') THEN 'Process'
                    ELSE 'NOT Process' END) "INITIATIVE"
        FROM
        "LIBRARY"."FACTSALES" T4
        , "LIBRARY"."CUSTOMER_TBL" T1
        , "LIBRARY"."PRODUCT_TBL" T2
        , "LIBRARY"."TIME_TBL" T3
        WHERE
        T4."CUSTOMER_KEY" = T1."CUSTOMER_KEY"
        AND T4."PRODUCT_KEY" = T2."PRODUCT_KEY"
        AND T4."DATE_KEY" = T3."DATE_KEY"
        AND T1."COUNTRY" IN ('Austria', 'Germany', 'France')
        AND T3."DATE_YEAR" BETWEEN '2012'AND '2016'
        AND T4."ORDER_VALUE" > 0
        GROUP BY
        T1."REGION"
        , T1."COUNTRY"
        , T1."CUSTID"
        , T1."CUSTOMER"
        , T1."VERTICAL"
        , T3."DATE_YEARMONTH"
        , T3."DATE_YEAR"
        , T4."ORDER_VALUE"
        , T3."DATE_DESC"
        , T2."BU_ID"
) SUBQRY )
WHERE "INITIATIVE" LIKE 'Process'
GROUP BY
"REGION"
, "COUNTRY"
, "CUSTID"
, "CUSTOMER"
, "VERTICAL"
, "DATE_YEARMONTH"
, "DATE_YEAR"
, "ORDER_VALUE"
, "INITIATIVE";
```

Lets say I get the following result on the example of a single customer:

```
   REGION       COUNTRY    CUSTID       CUSTOMER          VERTICAL      DATE_YEARMONTH      DATE_YEAR   ORDER_VALUE        INITIATIVE     TRANSACTION_FLAG
1. North         Germany    25166       Abraxo Cleaner    Chemicals     201201              2012        25.50              Process        New
2. North         Germany    25166       Abraxo Cleaner    Chemicals     201201              2012        45.50              Process        Existing
3. North         Germany    25166       Abraxo Cleaner    Chemicals     201405              2014        73.49              Process        Existing
4. North         Germany    25166       Abraxo Cleaner    Chemicals     201507              2015        156.29             Process        Existing
5. North         Germany     25166      Abraxo Cleaner    Chemicals     201511              2015        376.22             Process        Existing
```

As you can see line no. 1 was flagged as 'New'. All other lines were flagged as 'Existing' because these were booked in the database later than  the 1st line. However, line no. 2 was booked the same day.

What I would need to achieve is to SUM lines flagged 'New' with lines which are 'Existing' but fall into the same DATE_YEARMONTH. So going back to 5 lines above. I would need to sum lines no. 1 and 2. for the total value of 71.
Or maybe there is a simple way to FLAG such records, instead of SUMMING them up? This would allow me to SUM these up easily in excel when I download results of the query.

p.s.
If that's of any use, query used originates from my previous post: [Oracle SQL- Flag records based on record's date vs history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38183328/flag-records-based-on-records-date-vs-history).

Comment: When you say sum them - do you mean combine them into one line so the entire output would only be 4 lines? Does this only happen for the first month? For example, if you get two line items in 2015 in same month, they don't sum?

Comment: @ Peter M. I would not mind an outcome which would be 4 lines only. Actually, that might be even better. I would need to check two things:

1st) Count number of new transactions; And that's what this query was initially built around. Aim was not to count lines 1 and 2 as 2 new transactions.  

2nd) Later I was requested to sum values of new transactions as well. Therefore, summing up lines 1 and 2 to show as one line only with the value of 71 would work well. Of course there may be multiple lines, not only two, that could match the criteria.

Comment: You need to learn to indent, this is unreadable.

Comment: @Hogan My apologies for any inconvenience. I am a complete beginner who just started working with SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the bottom query to something like the below.

You would need to fix the other queries for my name change of ORDER_VALUE to ORDER_VALUE_TOTAL. Also introduce ORDER_COUNT in the other queries if you want to see it. Hopefully that bit will be easy to figure out.

```
SELECT
    T1."REGION"
    , T1."COUNTRY"
    , T1."CUSTID"
    , T1."CUSTOMER"
    , T1."VERTICAL"
    , T3."DATE_YEAR"
    , T3."DATE_YEARMONTH"
    , T3."DATE_DESC"
    , (CASE
                WHEN T2."BU_ID" IN ('ACC', 'LXC', 'OTP') THEN 'Process'
                ELSE 'NOT Process' END) "INITIATIVE"
    , SUM(T4."ORDER_VALUE") "ORDER_VALUE_TOTAL"
    , COUNT(*) "ORDER_COUNT"
    FROM
    "LIBRARY"."FACTSALES" T4
    , "LIBRARY"."CUSTOMER_TBL" T1
    , "LIBRARY"."PRODUCT_TBL" T2
    , "LIBRARY"."TIME_TBL" T3
    WHERE
    T4."CUSTOMER_KEY" = T1."CUSTOMER_KEY"
    AND T4."PRODUCT_KEY" = T2."PRODUCT_KEY"
    AND T4."DATE_KEY" = T3."DATE_KEY"
    AND T1."COUNTRY" IN ('Austria', 'Germany', 'France')
    AND T3."DATE_YEAR" BETWEEN '2012'AND '2016'
    AND T4."ORDER_VALUE" > 0
    GROUP BY
    T1."REGION"
    , T1."COUNTRY"
    , T1."CUSTID"
    , T1."CUSTOMER"
    , T1."VERTICAL"
    , T3."DATE_YEAR"
    , T3."DATE_YEARMONTH"
    , T3."DATE_DESC"
    , (CASE
            WHEN T2."BU_ID" IN ('ACC', 'LXC', 'OTP') THEN 'Process'
            ELSE 'NOT Process' END)
```